# FFmpeg takes long time to start

Tags: high-sierra, library

I recently compiled a full version of FFmpeg, and it would take around 2-5 seconds to start. Are there anyway to decrease this time?

When I say "it would take around 2-5 seconds to start", it means from executing the command to the first output (version and configuration information).

Below is the configure for ffmpeg:

```
--enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-gray --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gmp --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libjack --enable-libklvanc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-liblensfun --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libshine --enable-libsmbclient --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtensorflow --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxcb-shm --enable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-libxcb-shape --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-decklink --enable-libmysofa --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-vapoursynth --pkg-config-flags=--static
```

Below is the output of verbose dyld flags:

```
export DYLD_PRINT_OPTS=true
export DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS=true
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=true
export DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS_DETAILS=true
```

```
opt[0] = "ffmpeg"
opt[1] = "-hide_banner"
<loaded libraries are removed to comply with length limitation. For full log, see https://github.com/sclsj/log>
Total pre-main time: 2.5 seconds (100.0%)
         dylib loading time: 620.54 milliseconds (24.0%)
        rebase/binding time: 180.91 milliseconds (7.0%)
            ObjC setup time:  13.23 milliseconds (0.5%)
           initializer time: 1.7 seconds (68.4%)
           slowest intializers :
                      Kerberos :  56.18 milliseconds (2.1%)
       libopencv_dnn.3.4.dylib : 177.11 milliseconds (6.8%)
libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib : 207.32 milliseconds (8.0%)
            libtensorflow.so.2 : 961.39 milliseconds (37.2%)

  total time: 2.8 seconds (100.0%)
  total images loaded:  500 (251 from dyld shared cache)
  total segments mapped: 742, into 98568 pages with 1407 pages pre-fetched
  total images loading time: 620.54 milliseconds (21.5%)
  total load time in ObjC:  13.23 milliseconds (0.4%)
  total debugger pause time:   0.00 milliseconds (0.0%)
  total dtrace DOF registration time:   0.11 milliseconds (0.0%)
  total rebase fixups:  740,357
  total rebase fixups time: 171.27 milliseconds (5.9%)
  total binding fixups: 89,619
total binding symbol lookups: 433, average images searched per symbol: 1.0
  total binding fixups time: 300.06 milliseconds (10.4%)
  total weak binding fixups time:   6.50 milliseconds (0.2%)
  total redo shared cached bindings time: 296.93 milliseconds (10.3%)
  total bindings lazily fixed up: 0 of 415
  total time in initializers and ObjC +load: 1.7 seconds (61.3%)
                         libSystem.B.dylib :   5.28 milliseconds (0.1%)
                            CoreFoundation :   7.91 milliseconds (0.2%)
                                  Kerberos :  56.18 milliseconds (1.9%)
                         libopenal.1.dylib :   3.43 milliseconds (0.1%)
                             libGL.1.dylib :  10.65 milliseconds (0.3%)
                       libglib-2.0.0.dylib :   3.44 milliseconds (0.1%)
                        liblensfun.2.dylib :   3.85 milliseconds (0.1%)
                      libtesseract.5.dylib :  13.73 milliseconds (0.4%)
                  libopencv_core.3.4.dylib :   6.35 milliseconds (0.2%)
               libopencv_imgproc.3.4.dylib :   6.31 milliseconds (0.2%)
                   libopencv_dnn.3.4.dylib : 177.11 milliseconds (6.1%)
             libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.dylib :  37.51 milliseconds (1.3%)
               libopencv_videoio.3.4.dylib :   8.23 milliseconds (0.2%)
                 libopencv_flann.3.4.dylib :   8.73 milliseconds (0.3%)
             libopencv_objdetect.3.4.dylib :  12.15 milliseconds (0.4%)
                            libzmq.5.dylib :   6.87 milliseconds (0.2%)
           libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib : 207.32 milliseconds (7.2%)
                        libtensorflow.so.2 : 961.39 milliseconds (33.3%)
                        libmodplug.1.dylib :  10.57 milliseconds (0.3%)
                        libopenmpt.0.dylib :  45.76 milliseconds (1.5%)
             libvapoursynth-script.0.dylib :   6.04 milliseconds (0.2%)
                      libvapoursynth.dylib :  14.36 milliseconds (0.4%)
                      libgpg-error.0.dylib :   2.98 milliseconds (0.1%)
                     libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib :   4.55 milliseconds (0.1%)
                            libssh.4.dylib :  17.20 milliseconds (0.5%)
                        libp11-kit.0.dylib :   5.54 milliseconds (0.1%)
                        libgnutls.30.dylib :  28.48 milliseconds (0.9%)
                       libpixman-1.0.dylib :  16.61 milliseconds (0.5%)
                    libgobject-2.0.0.dylib :  20.28 milliseconds (0.7%)
                           libzvbi.0.dylib :   2.99 milliseconds (0.1%)
                         libx265.179.dylib :  34.94 milliseconds (1.2%)
                                    ffmpeg :   3.96 milliseconds (0.1%)
total symbol trie searches:    469136
total symbol table binary searches:    433
total images defining weak symbols:  48
total images using weak symbols:  120
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

Comment: I downloaded a binary, and "installed" it in `/usr/local/bin`. I see no such delay.

Comment: @Seamus Yes, because it's a static version and included much less components. I have a full build and although I want to build a static version, I don't know how to, so I end up with a shared version, I believe. Random read is still slower than sequential read.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I currently use `ffmpeg` primarily to "dumb down" some of my flac collection so the lame Sonos app can play them. I haven't needed anything beyond the defaults in the static ver. That said, if you learn how to build a static version, I'd like to hear about it. Good luck!     P.S. maybe try yr question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)?